# indexOf returns an error about object types, but it's the right class

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a `var cards: [Card]` collection in my app. I need to find the index of given card. Looking at the many answers here, I see Swift2 has `indexOf` and followed the example code exactly in this loop:

```
for c in cards {
    let num = cards.indexOf(c)
}
```

But that gives me the error:

`Cannot convert value of type 'Card' to expected argument type '@noescape (Card) throws -> Bool'`

I solved this by using this line instead:

```
let num = (cards as NSArray).indexOfObject(c)
```

Working is a feature, but I'd still really like to know why the "proper" method using indexOf fails. I suspect it's either that the parameter throws, or this method is overloaded and I'm failing to get the right one?

Comment: Make your `Card` inherit from `NSObject` should solve this problem `class Card: NSObject {} ` and should `.indexOfObject(c)` be `.indexOf(c)` ?

Comment: Please show us the declaration of `Card`.